# Local Storage QML, Get Sqlite Database Location

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, local-storage, qml

First of all sorry about the pretty basic question (i assume!)

I'm planning to use QtQuick.LocalStorage to create, read and write data to a local DB.

Now i want to know :

- Where does the Sqlite DB reside once its created using using
  LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync()?  (Documentation says we can utilise
  QQmlEngine::offlineStoragePath() function to get the location but I'm
  not sure how to run that function in QML :@)
- Can i specify the path for the DB to be created?/How?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value is not freely accessible within the QML environment, but it can be exported from the underlying code.
Within your `main` function in C++, you are probably declaring somewhere a `QQmlApplicationEngine` with something like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
```

You can use it to add a context property that contains the db location, as it follows:

```
// ...
auto offlineStoragePath = QUrl::fromLocalFile(engine.offlineStoragePath());
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("offlineStoragePath", offlineStoragePath);
// ...
```

From now on, you can simply use that value from within the QML environment by referring to it as `offlineStoragePath`. Try to put it in a `Label` by settings its `text` property as:

```
text: offlineStoragePath
```

Note that the member `offlineStoragePath` is part of the `QQmlEngine` class, from which `QQmlApplicationEngine` derives.
See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html) for further details.
As you can see, it also contains a member called `setOfflineStoragePath` (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#offlineStoragePath-prop)) that can be used to change the path for the storage.